# I broke the Java while() loop - firing on the wrong condition and freezing on the right one

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to code a skiplist for an algorithm's course and I'm having issues with my propagate method (called once an insertion point is found between A_prop and B_prop). Here's the code:

```
/* The randomized propagation upwards */
private void propagate(SkipNode<T> A_prop, SkipNode<T> B_prop, 
                       SkipNode<T> front_prop, SkipNode<T> end_prop, 
                       SkipNode<T> insert) 
{
    SkipNode<T> clone, rowBelow;
    Random random = new Random();
    float f = random.nextFloat();
    int flip = Math.round(f);

    A_prop.linkRight(insert);
    B_prop.linkLeft(insert);
    rowBelow = insert;

    System.out.println("Flip = " + flip);
    while(flip != 0);
    {
        System.out.println("HEADS");
        clone = insert.clone();

        // Insert node at this level
        A_prop.linkRight(clone);
        B_prop.linkLeft(clone);
        clone.linkDown(rowBelow);

        System.out.println("After Link");
        System.out.println(A_prop.right);
        System.out.println(insert);
        System.out.println(insert.right);
        System.out.println(B_prop);

        if(A_prop.up != null)
        { // Move up a row
            System.out.println("A up");
            A_prop = A_prop.up;
            B_prop = A_prop.right;
            front_prop = front_prop.up;
            end_prop = end_prop.up;
            rowBelow = clone;
        }
        else if(front_prop.up != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Front up");
            while(A_prop.up == null)
            {   // Find the closest node to the left that
                // has a copy in the above level
                A_prop = A_prop.left;
            }

            A_prop = A_prop.up;
            B_prop = A_prop.right;
            front_prop = front_prop.up;
            end_prop = end_prop.up;
            rowBelow = clone;
        }
        else // Create new top level
        {
            System.out.println("New row");
            // Make new terminal nodes
            A_prop = new SkipNode<T>("HEAD");
            B_prop = new SkipNode<T>("TAIL");
            // Link them to the current ones
            front_prop.linkUp(A_prop);
            end_prop.linkUp(B_prop);
            // Update current
            front_prop = front_prop.up;
            end_prop = end_prop.up;
            // Link 'em
            front_prop.linkRight(end_prop);
            // To be sure
            A_prop = front_prop;
            B_prop = end_prop;

            rowBelow = clone;
        }

        f = random.nextFloat();
        flip = Math.round(f);       
    }

    // Don't forget to update the global head and tail for the list
    head = front_prop;
    tail = end_prop;
}
```

I still have some debugging println()'s in place; the output I'm getting on the console is one of two cases:

### Case 1:

Flip = 1

### Case 2:

Flip = 0

HEADS

In Case 1, the programs is still running (I need to hit the little red box on the console to break), but no more code executes. I've put println()'s after the while loop and nothing print's and I've commented out everything inside the loop - no effect. My computer runs loud and hot until I restart Eclipse.

In Case 2, the program keeps going until it hits Case 1...

All four link methods are tested and working. I've tried restarting my computer and I even went as far as reinstalling Java(version 1.7.0_45). I have no clue what could be causing this and any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please review this line of code ... There shouldn't be any semicolon to terminate the while loop !!!

```
while(flip != 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something silly that I was code-blind to.

Answer (score 0):

@Roshan is correct..
you can use semicolon with your loop when you want to execute single line after loop.
But you have written multiple line after termination of loop.It'll not work.When you use braces to specify a block for your while you don't use a semicolon.
Please recheck.